# Python continue if xml element name is not present

Tags: python, xml

There are 2 kinds of XML output I may get-

Output 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BESAPI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BESAPI.xsd">
    <Action>
        <ActionID>123</ActionID>
    </Action>
</BESAPI>
```

Output 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BESAPI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BESAPI.xsd">
    <Action>
        <ActionID>789</ActionID>
        <Computer ID="456">
            <Status>The action is successful.</Status>
        </Computer>
    </Action>
</BESAPI>
```

I want to print Computer Status to a list if present. If not, print Action ID.

This is the code I have but it does not give any result for XML Output 1-

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
actionstatuslist = []
doc = ET.parse('actionstatus.xml')
root = doc.getroot()

for elem in root.findall('.//Computer'):
    for subelem in elem.findall('Status'):
        if subelem is None:
            for el in root.iter('Action'):
                for subel in el.iter('ActionID'):
                    actionid = int(subel.text)
                    print(actionid)
        else:
            actionstatuslist.append(subelem.text)
```

Desired result for XML Output 1-

```
123
```

I'm getting the correct Computer Status result for XML Output 2 though-

```
'The action is successful.'
```

I need help with Output 1 scenario.

Comment: what is the output of `print(elem.findall('Status'))`

Comment: @OsadhiVirochana - I get: `[<Element 'Status' at 0x7feafe0ab850>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `root.findall('.//Computer')` returns empty list(`[]`) it doesn't execute

```
for elem in root.findall('.//Computer'):
    for subelem in elem.findall('Status'):
        if subelem is None:
            for el in root.iter('Action'):
                for subel in el.iter('ActionID'):
                    actionid = int(subel.text)
                    print(actionid)
        else:
            actionstatuslist.append(subelem.text)
```

So at first, you need to check if `root.findall('.//Computer')` is empty and then check if `elem.findall('Status')` is empty. If one if them are empty then run

```
for el in root.iter('Action'):
    for subel in el.iter('ActionID'):
        actionid = int(subel.text)
        print(actionid)
```

It is easier if you use it as a function

Final code will be like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
actionstatuslist = []
doc = ET.parse('actionstatus.xml')
root = doc.getroot()

def get_action_id():
    for el in root.iter('Action'):
        for subel in el.iter('ActionID'):
            actionid = int(subel.text)
            print(actionid)
    

if root.findall('.//Computer'):
    for elem in root.findall('.//Computer'):
        if elem.findall('Status'):
            for subelem in elem.findall('Status'):
                actionstatuslist.append(subelem.text)
        else:
            get_action_id()               
else:    
    get_action_id()
```

Edit in final code(Added requested features in comments):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
actionstatuslist = []
doc = ET.parse('actionstatus.xml')
root = doc.getroot()

def get_action_id():
    for el in root.iter('Action'):
        for subel in el.iter('ActionID'):
            actionid = int(subel.text)
            print(actionid)
    
get_action_id()
for elem in root.findall('.//Computer'):
    if elem.findall('Status'):
        for subelem in elem.findall('Status'):
            actionstatuslist.append(subelem.text)
            print(elem.get('ID'))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!! How do I also print the ActionID from XML Output 2?
Right now it only prints the status. I want its corresponding ID.
Desired output - `789 and 456`

Comment: You can get ActionID by adding `nope()` after `actionstatuslist.append(subelem.text)`. Can you mention what do you want to do so I can write a better code?

Comment: For Output 1:
Desired output - `123` (This works now)

For Output 2:
Desired output - `789 456`

Comment: @jenhenry I changed the code as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks but the edited code only provides computer ID `456`. I want `789` also...

Comment: I'm referring to the Output 2 scenario

Comment: You will see when you run it. I moved `get_action_id()` before `for elem in root.findall('.//Computer')`. So you can get `123` in output1 and `789` in output 2. This is the output of output2 `789
456`

Comment: Oh yes, my bad! Moving the get_action_id() worked! Thanks much

Comment: I am glad to hear. Why did you remove the list thing? I am happy to help you.

Comment: I figured out the list thing :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
actionstatuslist = []
doc = ET.parse('actionstatus.xml')
root = doc.getroot()

for child in root.iter('Action'):
    grand_child=child.find("Computer/Status")
    if grand_child != None:
        actionstatuslist.append(grand_child.text)
    else:
        temp=child.find("ActionID")
        actionstatuslist.append(temp.text)
```

First we've got the `Action` tag inside child and we are looking for `Computer/Status`,using a `if` or we are going to just get the `ActionID` .